# Is there a way to support nested resources in the ember REST adapter?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

The default REST Adapter expects a model like this where the dependent objects are loaded alongside the one they have a many-to-one relationship with.

```
{
  object: {
    ...
  }
  dependentObjects: [
    ...
  ]
}
```

But is there any adapter that supports data in a nested format like this?

```
{
  object: {
    ...
    dependentObjects: [
       ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be looking for embedded records, see DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed records in your response from API, but you need to configure your serializer properly:

```
App.ParentSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  isNewSerializerAPI: true,
  attrs: {
    children: { embedded: 'always' }
  }
});
```

Then, you could serialize following response:

```
{
    parents: [
        {
            id: 1,
            children: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'a'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

- [Working demo.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sumofo/4/edit?html,js,output)
- [Read more about embedded records.](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html)